# Simple Apex Trigger Help

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create a Simple Apex Trigger that performs an update to the custom "Chargent Order" record whenever one is created or edited. I want it to look through a relationship field "Finacial Statement" and grab a few fields from it and then update them down to the Chargent Order that started the Trigger.

I am not receiving any errors but the fields simply are not updating. I am probably missing something very simple that I am just not seeing any help would be appreciated. My code is below:

```
trigger ChargentOrderPopulateACHInformation on ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c (before insert, before update) {

    for(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c co : 
        [SELECT ChargentOrders__Bank_Account_Number__c, 
                ChargentOrders__Bank_Routing_Number__c, 
                ChargentOrders__Bank_Account_Type__c, 
                Financial_Statement__r.ACHAccountType__c, 
                Financial_Statement__r.ACH_Account_Number__c, 
                Financial_Statement__r.ACHRoutingNumber__c 
         FROM ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c WHERE Id IN: Trigger.new]){

                 co.ChargentOrders__Bank_Account_Number__c = co.Financial_Statement__r.ACH_Account_Number__c;
                 co.ChargentOrders__Bank_Routing_Number__c = co.Financial_Statement__r.ACHRoutingNumber__c;
                 co.ChargentOrders__Bank_Account_Type__c = co.Financial_Statement__r.ACHAccountType__c;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free record update that you get with `before insert` and `before update` triggers only works if you modify the instances of the records that are stored in `trigger.new` or `trigger.newmap`

Performing a query creates separate in-memory instances of those records.

You'll need to iterate over `trigger.new` directly for this to work.
You'll still want to perform your query outside of your loop using `WHERE Id IN :trigger.new`.

The last thing to be aware of is that your query won't return any records in `before insert`, because your records aren't inserted into the database until just before the `after insert` trigger event is fired.

Comment: I tried using After instead of Before and that threw some errors. I also did not think I needed to use after seeing as I do not need the Record ID of the new record. All I am doing is updating some fields on the record as it is being created. I do not fully understand your suggestions. Would you mind modifying my code about to help me understand what you are getting at? Thanks

Comment: I went back and spent some more time looking into this and was able to get it resolved. Thanks so much for the help.